# C++Builder: Cannot debug 64 bit app

Tags: c++, debugging, c++builder

I'm trying to check out 64 bit C++ compiler of Embarcadero C++Builder (as it is Clang based, I hope it will better conform to the standard). But the problem is that I cannot debug anything: breakpoints just does not work.

I do the following:

- Create new project
- Save all files with some names
- Replace the whole content of the cpp file with classic "hello world" source like this:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <ostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
      cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- Right-click "Target Platforms" and create 64 bit platform. Make it active.
- Build the debug configuration. In output window I see that Clang based compiler is used.
- Set break point at "return" statement.
- Start debugging (e.g. with F9)

Result:
The application runs OK, but breakpoints are shown crossed (as if no debug information is available) and they are not triggered, so application exits immediately.

The documentation says, that debugging should work basically the same as for 32 bit compiler, but for some reason it does not. I'd highly appreciate if someone could tell me what may be the reason.

Notes:

1. Debugging for 32 bit platform works just fine for me.
2. I tried 64 bit debugging on two versions: XE6 and XE8 - the behavior is the same for both versions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you set your breakpoint before the `returen`? E.g., at `cout` line.

Comment: Of course, I tried it and It also does not work. And as I wrote, when I start the debugger, it shows the breakpoint marks crossed, like if the debugging symbols are not available... By the way, I don't know if it is possible to see somewhere in the debugger in C++Builder, which symbols was loaded and which not...